# Confused how to access C++ variable within assembly code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, inline-assembly

Taking a class on assembly and all the programming is done in visual studio using the _asm command. This is the template for the assignment I'm working on:

```
void main ()
    {
    const unsigned char c1 (0x11);
    const unsigned char c2 (0x22);
    const unsigned char c3 (0x33);
    const unsigned char c4 (0x44);
    unsigned long i1 (0);
    _asm
        {
        **CODE HERE**
        }
     cout << "result is " << hex << i1 << endl;
    }
```

Instructions: Inside the block denoted by the _asm keyword, add code to put the values of c1, c2, c3, and c4 (each 8 bits) into the eax register with c1 being loaded at the high (most significant end) and c4 at the low end. Put the 32 bit result into i1.

How do I access the variables that are declared in C++? I thought that there's no such thing as a 'variable' in assembly so how am I supposed to access these ones?

Comment: You just [access it by name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/accessing-c-or-cpp-data-in-asm-blocks).  You aren't writing pure assembly, you're writing MSVC embedded assembly.

Comment: Can your asm take advantage of the fact that they're constants, and do `mov eax, (c1<<24) | (c2<<16) | ...` with one instruction whose immediate is computed at compile time?  Or do you have to let MSVC put them in memory and then `mov al, c1` and shift?  (Or any number of other ways that don't involve writing partial registers?)

Comment: going the other way: [How to move bytes of a variable in assembly](//stackoverflow.com/q/59990334)

Answer (score 0):

Example of addition of those numbers with Visual Studio.

```
#include <iostream>

int main( )
{
    const unsigned char c1 (0x11);
    const unsigned char c2 (0x22);
    const unsigned char c3 (0x33);
    const unsigned char c4 (0x44);
    unsigned long i1 (0);
    _asm
    {
            xor     eax,eax
            xor     ecx,ecx         ;xor and mov could be replaced with movzx ecx,c1
            mov     cl,c1
            add     eax,ecx
            mov     cl,c2
            add     eax,ecx
            mov     cl,c3
            add     eax,ecx
            mov     cl,c4
            add     eax,ecx
            mov     i1,eax
    }
    std::cout << "result is " << std::hex << i1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that inline assembly is not allowed in 64 bit programs, which require a separate source file in order to mix assembly code with C or C++ code.

Comment: This computes `c1+c2+c3+c4`, not packing those bytes into one dword as  `c1:c2:c3:c4`.  This is an example of how to access variables without doing the OP's homework for them, though.  (You can use `movzx ecx, c1` to avoid xor-zeroing ECX first)

Comment: @PeterCordes - what about the number of clocks or uops for |xor ecx|mov cl,c1| vesus |movzx ecx,c1| ? Lost an edit describing the code, it's fixed now.

Comment: `movzx r32, m8` is single-uop, not even micro-fused (fully handled by a load port) on Intel for a long time.  Same on Zen 1 and Zen 2, according to https://uops.info/.  Same latency as a 32-bit `mov` load.  It costs 1 extra byte of code-size per load, but making each load write the full register removes the serial dependency between loads, and any need for a merging uop.

Comment: Xor-zeroing will avoid any partial-register penalties (e.g. P6-family or early SnB) for writing `cl` and reading `ecx` (unless an interrupt arrives between the zeroing and the `mov r8,m8` so save/restore of the reg destroys that.)  But on modern Intel (HSW and later which don't rename cl separately from ECX) `mov cl, mem`  costs 1 *micro-fused* load+merge uop.  It goes through the front-end as a single uop, but in the back end an ALU uop has to execute to merge the load result into ECX before `add` can read it.  So it takes more space in the RS, and more latency (in a short independent chain)

Comment: **Rule of thumb: only use `mov r8, ...` if you specifically *want* to merge into the low byte of the previous value**.  Otherwise use the RISC-like style of a zero-extending or sign-extending load.  (Some CPUs (like AMD Bulldozer maybe?) need an extra uop to sign-extend a byte or word load; recent Intel / AMD do movsx loads purely in a load port as well.)  There can be cases where saving 1 byte of code size is more useful, e.g. in cold code where its own performance isn't critical, or if you know for your target CPU that partial-reg stuff works out fine.

Comment: BTW, if you just want to provide an example of using var names in inline asm syntax, I think there are existing duplicates which ask that.  So we could just close this question as a dup.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I added a comment in my answer rather than change the code so that your comments would still apply. On 486, xor+mov is 2 cycles, movzx is 3 cycles, at some point after the 486, the movzx became faster, but I don't know when. Since addition wasn't the goal here, I wasn't thinking about optimizing my example code, and I was trying to make the pattern of mov + add the same for the 4 pairs of instructions.

Comment: Fair enough, although in 2020 I don't think anyone cares about tuning for 486 or in-order P5 (where `movzx` is also slow).  However, partial-register shenanigans (and shifts) is actually the most efficient way to get the OP's task done on most CPUs, except P6 family where partial-reg merge stalls are actually serious.  But it still works there, and is easy, so perhaps that `mov` load example will help them.  On Intel HSW/SKL, movzx + shl + 3x mov and 2 more shifts would work, only loading into AL.  Loading AH and AL might be worse if front-end bottlenecked (AH merge uop has to issue by itself)

Comment: Just to quibble: I know you didn't pick the variable names, but using code like `cl,c1` is just asking for trouble.  Depending upon the font, these two names can easily be confused.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd - In this case, it should be clear that the moves are from memory to register. Again, this is just an example showing the syntax for accessing local variables with assembly. The actual assignment is to pack the 4 separate bytes into a single integer.

Comment: Depending upon the font, lower case L and the number 1 can be difficult to distinguish.  Typing one when you meant the other would be easy to do, and difficult to see during a visual inspection.  For example `mov cl,cl` would assemble, but could lead to serious head-scratching when it doesn't move the value from `c1` the way you expected it to.  Since variable names are typically under the control of the programmer, using `uc1` for unsigned char #1 could avoid this potential for confusion.

Comment: Ok so I can just access them by name within the assembly code?